# ProductImport Field separator TAB

Tags: magento2, import

How can I use TAB as Field separator in Magento 2 csv product import settings?
I have try with /t and TAB but i get error (with comma Field separator it works fine)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default Magento 2 is not support tab separator, you can use free version of our Improved Import & Export extension where we have implement it https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexportfree

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a magento core file, but the correct way is to create a module following the same structure.
But if you want to change the COLOR directly, this file is at:
**/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/File/Write.php**
You can change on line 72:
*public function writeCsv(array $data, $delimiter = '**,**', $enclosure = '"')*
By default it is "," but the character you put here will be used for all exports.